# Blocking thread for wait queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have applications with 2 threads. In first (main) thread I want to generate some message and send it to second thread. Is there method to blocked thread for wait incoming message (like a queue in embended OS(FreeRTOS, TNKernel etc))?

```
while (true) {
   waitQueue(TIMEOUT_INFINITY); 
}
```

in `waitQueue(TIMEOUT_INFINITY);` current thread becomes blocked, when in main thread generates some message `waitQueue` releases thread.

Comment: Method **where**? There is no such method in standard C++. There is such method in other libraries.

Comment: He probably is looking for [QT event queues](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html#high-level-event-queues).

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for Qt. But I didn't get how to use that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way for doing this in Qt is calling `QThread::exec()` in the thread (which is what the default implementation for `QThread::run()` do).

after that to execute a `QObject` instance (worker object)'s slots in that thread, you can set the instance's affinity to the new thread using `QObject::moveToThread()`, then when a signal connected to some slot in that instance is emitted, the slot will be invoked in the new thread.

> Instantiating a QThread provides a parallel event loop, allowing QObject slots to be invoked in a secondary thread. Subclassing a QThread allows the application to initialize the new thread before starting its event loop, or to run parallel code without an event loop.

see [QThread class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html), [QObject class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html), [Threads and QObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html), along with [Qt event loops](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html#high-level-event-queues).

Hope this helps. . .